# Eliminate for-loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization

I have to compute some quantities in python using the following formula: (I'll post an Image since LaTeX language is not recognized)

[image]

where "psi" is simply the digamma function, v_j and alpha_{t, bl}^{l} are floating numbers with t={0, 1, 2}, bl = {0, 1, 2, 3} and l = {1, 2, ..., 309}.

For now I have solved grouping v_j into a list and the alphas into nested dictionaries (in order: l, t, bl), iterating the formula with three for loops:

```
for loop in tqdm(range(500)):
logr = []
for t in range(3):
    add1 = digamma(V[t]) - digamma(sum(V))
    add2 = 0
    for b in test.columns[2:-1]:
        add2 += digamma(alphas[b][t][test.iloc[395][b]]) - digamma(sum(alphas[b][t])) 
    logrho = add1 + add2
    logr.append(logrho)
rho = np.exp(logr)
q = rho/sum(rho)
```

The problem is that I have to iterate these lines of code for hundreds of time. So, I am looking for a way to eventually vectorize my problem. My first guess was to convert the "alpha dictionary" into a dataframe (`pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`) but still I can't get rid of the for loops.

Is there a better way to tackle the problem? Maybe creating a three dimensional pandas dataframe?

EDIT

The real problem I am struggling to figure out is about the second part of the equation (let me forget about the digamma function). The alpha parameters have 3 dimensions: t=0,1,2; l=1,2,...,N and bl=0,1,2,3. Assume we fix t so that we end up iterating only over t=0,1,2. The alpha parameters can be represented in a two dimensional dataframe:

```
bl     l1     l2     l3     ...     lN
0      a0l1   a0l2   a0l3           a0lN
1      a1l1   a1l2   a1l3           a1lN
2      ...
3      a3l1   ...                   a3lN
```

I should't subtract the sum over the the column from each alpha, but only from one of the four classes bl=0,1,2,3.
If in the data, the variable l1 provides an outcome of 3, I should subtract the sum of the alphas for column l1 from a3l1; if the outcome in l2 is 0, i should subtract the sum of the alphas of column l2 from a0l2 and so on. Finally, the sum of the results will be summed (sum over l)

Comment: Start by ensuring that your `digamma` implementation itself is vectorized.  You seem to need all the `digamma(alphas)` values,  all the values of `digamma(alphas.sum(axis=2))`, all the values of `digamma(V)` and the single scalar value `digamma(V.sum())`. In each of those cases, why keep computing them in a loop when, with an appropriate `digamma` implementation, you can take one line to pre-compute each of these across its whole array argument?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have edited my question since it wasn't clear my problem from the original formulation.